# Some strange questions about pytorch copy a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am a bit confused about pytorch's shared memory mechanism.

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0],
                                   [0,1,1,0]])
b = a
b[b == 1] = 0
```

It's easy to know that `a` and `b` will simutaneously become `tensor([[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])`, cause `a` and `b` share the same memory. When I changed the code to

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0],
                                   [0,1,1,0]])
b = a
b = b - 1
```

`b` became `tensor([[0,-1,0,-1],[-1,0,0,-1]])`, but `a` is still `torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0]])`. 
`a` and `b` are sharing the same memory. Why did `b` changed, while `a` didn't change?

Comment: torch.tensor() always copies data. If you have a Tensor data and just want to change its requires_grad flag, use requires_grad_() or detach() to avoid a copy. If you have a numpy array and want to avoid a copy, use torch.as_tensor(). From the documentation.

Comment: So now that b is the copy of a, and they point to the same address, why changing b has no affect to a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example `a` and `b` share the same reference but `b = b - 1` is actually a copy. You are not affecting the underlying data of `b` (and not of `a` neither since it's the same).

- You can look at it this way:

  ```
  >>> a = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,0]])
  >>> b1 = a
  >>> b2 = b1 - 1
  ```

  Comparing their pointer to the data buffers:

  ```
  >>> a.data_ptr() == b1.data_ptr()
  True

  >>> b1.data_ptr() == b2.data_ptr()
  False
  ```
- If in fact, you operate on `b` inplace, you will of course change `a` as well:

  ```
  >>> a = torch.tensor([[1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,0]])
  >>> b1 = a
  >>> b1.sub_(1)
  ```

  Then you haven't made a copy:

  ```
  >>> a.data_ptr() == b1.data_ptr()
  True
  ```

Comment: So "b = b - 1" save b in a new address, then it won't change "a". Thank u so much!